# How do I log into AWS before pulling image from ECR?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-ecr

I'm pulling image into my pipeline from ECR. First I need to authenticate using
`eval $(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-2 --no-include-email | sed 's|https://||')`

however I don't have an idea how to use it within CI workflow since this should run
before the image is pulled:

```
e2e:
  stage: test
  image: 2xxxxxxxxxxxxx8.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/training-users_db
  services:
   - postgres:12.2-alpine
  variables:
    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    AWS_SECRET_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    POSTGRES_DB: users
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    DATABASE_TEST_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/users
    FLASK_ENV: development
    SECRET_KEY: $SECRET_KEY
  script:
    - eval $(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-2 --no-include-email | sed 's|https://||')
```

How can I log into ECR right before the image is pulled ?

Comment: Are you using a gitlab shared runner or a runner using EC2?

Comment: @Thorax  I'm using shared runners.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I've found for documentation on this:
https://mherman.org/blog/gitlab-ci-private-docker-registry/
But I haven't been able to get it to work as described yet. I still get some authentication errors when it tries to pull my image. I have a support ticket open to try and figure it out, but maybe you can get it working?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've implemented what I've learned from the blog post. By far not working. Still throws "no basic auth credentials". I've reached out to the author of the post if he can provide more details.